# Excel Formula to calculate SD and SUMSQ based on 4 conditions. 2 of the conditions will determine from which column the data will be taken from

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-statements, array-formulas, standard-deviation

I am having problems building two formulas with 4 conditions to return the Sum of Squares and the Standard Deviation from a dataset:

[image: screenshot of table]

First two conditions. Located in data validation cells outside of the data range:

- KPI
- Period of time

Second two conditions:

- Campaign Name
- Player Group = Target Vs Control

The basic idea is that a player will generate a value for a series of KPIs over different periods of time (7,14 and 28 days). Therefore the structure of the data sets will be defined as:

Columns:

- Player ID
- Campaign ID
- Player Group: Target or Contol
- Rest of the columns: Combinations of a KPI and a given period of time.

The objective is to calculate the SD and SUMSQ of a subset of data based on the following restrictions: the KPI, the period of time, the Campaign ID and the Group of the player. As the dataset is built, the conditions "KPI" and "Period" will determine the column from which the data is going to be taken and the conditions "Campaign" and "Player Group" will act as row filters.

I have tried the following... with little hope, since I don't even expect that an array formula can be nested in an "if" function:

```
=IF(AND(Test!$J$9="STAKES",Test!$M$9=7),STDEV.S(IF(DATA!$A$2:$A$9237=Test!$B$13,DATA!$AD$2:$AD$9237,0)))
```

Can someone come up with a solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting close.  The "0" is where your next "if statement" will go.
So if the first "AND" condition is false the next "if statement" in the position where "0" was will execute.

Instead of $J$9="STAKES" and $M$9=7 I changed it to $J$9="TACOS" and $M$9=9000.

```
=IF(AND(Test!$J$9="STAKES",Test!$M$9=7),STDEV.S(IF(DATA!$A$2:$A$9237=Test!$B$13,DATA!$AD$2:$AD$9237,IF(AND(Test!$J$9="TACOS",Test!$M$9=9000),STDEV.S(IF(DATA!$A$2:$A$9237=Test!$B$13,DATA!$AD$2:$AD$9237,0))))))
```